# Img Src Not Working - Genesis

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple question, you might know it.

```
<img src="images/sample.jpg" />
```

In a regular wordpress theme it should be like this ..

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/sample.jpg" />
```

Right?

What about in Genesis themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Genesis child theme, you should reference the stylesheet directory:

```
src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Every theme consist their own user defined functions to implement the functionality to expend more functionality beside basic that you are using.

I am not familiar with the Genesis theme, but i also used CANVAS and many more. It is up on the theme developer that how do he/she used the trick so that the theme functionality will be easily to extend.

Let's take and example:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/sample.jpg" />
```

the alternative of this:

```
function get_template_image( $image_name = "sample.jpg" ){
echo '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/'. $image_name .'" />';
}
```

and add this function into the `functions.php` file. and call it like this.

```
get_template_image( "sample.jpg" );
```